# I cannot write the '@'symbol

Tags: symbols, characters

how can I write the around '@'  symbol in LaTex? I'm trying to input some text inside a lslisting:

```
\begin{lstlisting} 
     @some text some text
\end{lstlisting}
```

The '@' doesn't come up or sometimes it gives me an error
How do I make it work please?

Comment: make a complete example, without it we can't say what you are doing to break @ which normally works fine.

Comment: A MWE such as `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting} 
     @some text some text
\end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}` compiles perfectly fine on my system and results in the following output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBSrO.png

Answer (score 1):

Does this compile what you want?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{listings} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{lstlisting}       
@some text some text 
\end{lstlisting}



\end{document}
```